# Android SDK ~ Cloud Vision: WARNING: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-platform, vision

### I have follow WARNING when I"m run Gradle

### Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the dependency. Ad the following code to your build.gradle and rebuild the project and your warning should go away.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```